# Rewrite rules overwriting subfolders htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess in /public_html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is that if i go to /public_html/anotherFolder , then it doesn't realise there is another folder with its own htaccess and index.php file. It just passes the parameters to public_html/index.php

How do I get around this?

Comment: What is the contents of your htaccess file in the subfolder? Add it to the question.

Comment: Do you have rewrite rules in `/public_html/anotherFolder/.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the subfolder had permissions problems. In other words, the subfolder was throwing an error, which caused the top-level htaccess file to ignore the second level's htaccess file.

Moral of the story: always remove upper-level htaccess file and make sure lower htaccess file works without upper-level one.